# How can I substitute Unicode characters with ASCII in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I can do it in vim like so:

```
:%s/\%u2013/-/g
```

How do I do the equivalent in Perl? I thought this would do it but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\x{2013}/-/g' my.dat
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For a generic solution, [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Unidecode/) transliterate pretty much anything that's thrown at it into pure US-ASCII.

So in your case this would work:

```
perl -C -MText::Unidecode -n -i -e'print unidecode( $_)' unicode_text.txt
```

The -C is there to make sure the input is read as utf8

It converts this:

```
l'été est arrivé à peine après aôut
¿España es un paìs muy lindo?
some special chars: » « ® ¼ ¶ – – — Ṉ
Some greek letters: β ÷ Θ ¬ the α and ω (or is it Ω?)
hiragana? みせる です
Здравствуйте
السلام عليكم
```

into this:

```
l'ete est arrive a peine apres aout
?Espana es un pais muy lindo?
some special chars: >> << (r) 1/4 P - - -- N
Some greek letters: b / Th ! the a and o (or is it O?)
hiragana? miseru desu
Zdravstvuitie
lslm `lykm
```

The last one shows the limits of the module, which can't infer the vowels and get as-salaamu `alaykum from the original arabic. It's still pretty good I think

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick for me:

```
perl -C1 -i -pe 's/–/-/g' my.dat
```

Note that the first bar is the \x{2013} character itself.

Comment: Some explanation of the '-C1' would do wonders.  The information is available at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html (-C1 means 'standard input is in UTF8').

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, a bit tough.  This seems to do it (Perl 5.10.0 on MacOS X 10.6.2):

```
perl -w -e "
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
use open ':std';

while (<>)
{
    s/\x{2013}/-/g;
    print;
}
"
```

I have not yet minimized that.  See [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) on the 'use open' statement.

---

Judging from my (limited) experiments, the '-p' option doesn't recognize the 'use open' directives.
You can use 'qw()' to quote the words:

```
perl -w -e "
use open qw( :encoding(utf8) :std );
while (<>)
{
    s/\x{2013}/-/g;
    print;
}
```

I don't know if '-p' not obeying 'use open' is a bug or a design feature.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could just specify the UTF-8 encoding of the characters you want to substitute:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\xE2\x80\x93/-/g' my.dat
```

Here hex value E28093 is the UTF-8 encoding of hex value 2013. You can find various tools online to get the UTF-8 encoding for a character, or you can just look at my.dat in a hex editor.