# Perl unicode conversion

Tags: perl, unicode

I'm using this code:

```
use Unicode::UTF8 qw[decode_utf8 encode_utf8];
my $d = "opposite Spencer\u2019s Aliganj, Lucknow";
my $string = decode_utf8($d);
my $octets = encode_utf8($d);
print "\nSTRING :: $string";
```

I want output like

```
opposite Spencer's Aliganj, Lucknow
```

what to do ?

Comment: And how is `Unicode::UTF8` supposed to determine that U+2019 should be translated to an apostrophe?

Comment: Do you want `'` (an ASCII apostrophe) or `’` (a Unicode quotation mark, the codepoint 0x2019)?

Comment: If you want to convert a Unicode string to ASCII, this is a duplicate of [How can I substitute Unicode characters with ASCII in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309215/how-can-i-substitute-unicode-characters-with-ascii-in-perl).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want `unicode #2019` to become `’` you can use one of this ways:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':std', ':encoding(utf-8)';
print chr(0x2019);
print "\x{2019}";  # for characters 0x100 and above
print "\N{U+2019}";
```

`\u \U` in perl translates to uppercase in perl:

> Case translation operators use the Unicode case translation tables
>   when character input is provided. Note that uc(), or \U in
>   interpolated strings, translates to uppercase, while ucfirst, or \u in
>   interpolated strings, translates to titlecase in languages that make
>   the distinction (which is equivalent to uppercase in languages without
>   the distinction).

Comment: Hi Suic, I want variable $d content need to change.

Comment: `my $d = "opposite Spencer\N{U+2019}s Aliganj, Lucknow";` is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse butchered JSON.

You could parse it yourself.

```
use Encode qw( decode );

my $incomplete_json = "opposite Spencer\u2019s Aliganj, Lucknow";

my $string = $incomplete_json;
$string =~ s{\\u([dD][89aAbB]..)\\u([dD][cCdDeEfF]..)|\\u(....)}
            { $1 ? decode('UTF-16be', pack('H*', $1.$2)) : chr(hex($3)) }eg;
```

Or you could fix it up then use an existing parser

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $incomplete_json = "opposite Spencer\u2019s Aliganj, Lucknow";

my $json = $incomplete_json;
$json =~ s/"/\\"/g;
$json = qq{["$json"]};

my $string = decode_json($json)->[0];
```

Untested. You may have to handle other slashes. Which solution is simpler depends on how you have to handle the other slashes.